# Can I transfer data from an old Dell laptop to an external hard drive and then be able to transfer it to a new Apple laptop

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, external-hard-drive

My daughter has a new Apple laptop. Her old laptop is an older Dell Inspiron. It runs Windows XP. The Dell has pictures and videos of her son (my grandson), we want to transfer to an external hard drive. My question is, can the data that is transferred to the external hard drive from Windows XP be transferred to her new Apple laptop which runs Mac OS/X?

Comment: What version of OSX is on the Mac? Mavericks?

Comment: Directly copy the files and paste it to Mac PC. It's an easy way. If you take help of Windows Easy Transfer, it might not be compatible with Mac.

Comment: @MarksPCSolution Windows Easy Transfer doesn't work on a Mac. In any case you can do a transfer with no additional software: Share the folder on the Windows side, connect to it on the Mac side (Macs have native support for SMB/CIFS, although in Mavericks it seems there's a potential bug and the workaround is to [use cifs:// instead of smb:// for the protocol](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/10/27/did-mavericks-kill-your-network-drive-access-heres-a-fix/)).

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any problem. Just make sure the external hard drive is formatted with a file system compatible with both Windows XP and Mac OS X.
(Probably it's already shipped with a compatible one but it is worth checking).

Then just copy your data to the external drive and from there to the Mac.

Alternatively, if the two computers are on the same network, you can also avoid passing from the external drive and setup a shared folder between them. It could be slightly more complicated than passing from the external drive but it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

If the external drive is formatted as FAT you will have no issues at all.

If it is formatted as NTFS you can read it on the Mac but may have to jump through a few hoops, and you will definitely have to take extra steps to be able to *write* to it from the Mac. If you're using Mavericks I *think* it can read NTFS natively and you *probably* won't have any issues.

So to guarantee an easy time, format the external drive as FAT first, if it's not already, then copy your data to it, then you'll be 100% fine. Note that if you format the drive you will lose any data that already exists on it.

If you want to check the *current* format of the external drive, attach it to your Windows computer, right click the drive and choose "Properties". It should tell you the file system type there. I suggest checking first because if it's already FAT then you don't have to waste time and effort formatting it, and it will already be good to go.

---

Another option to transfer is to skip the external drive entirely and do it over your home network. Instructions for this and many other options for transferring files from PC to Mac can be found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Transfer-Files-from-PC-to-Mac). Note that, for the network-based methods, transferring files over wifi will most likely be a few orders of magnitude slower than using the external drive you were planning on using (which is a good plan, but just throwing some other options out there FYI).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But you have to watch out for your external Hard Drive's [file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_System).

Macs are unable to work with the NTFS file system (the one Windows use) due to the system architecture, however if your hard drive is formatted in FAT-32, you should be able to copy them from one system to another fine.
If your hard drive is formatted in the NTFS file system however... You can use commercial programs such as Tuxera but I recommend a program I've been using (it's free) - [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com.au/). Other than that - If it is formatted in the FAT32 format, you should be fine.
*Note that the following programs are to be installed on the Mac you're copying the files to... And not the Windows PC.*

EDIT: I think NTFS-3G has been bought over by Tuxera.. And it's not free anymore.

Comment: Macs can read NTFS no problem

Comment: I didn't know that... My older macs (10.5 and before) don't support NTFS.

Comment: they may not have been able to *write* to NTFS, but I've been able to *read* NTFS drives going back to at least OS X 10.3. 95% sure I was able to read on 8.6, too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really informative article on Migration Assistant: what it does, what it transfers, what it doesn't transfer, where to download it from (to the Dell), how to install (on the Dell) and how to **use** it, etc: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4796

You can connect the computers through ethernet or wifi. Newer Macs will require an ethernet to Thunderbolt adapter (except for the last non-retina MacBook pro build with the optical drive). Sometimes IEEE 1394 will work too, but ethernet will probably be easier.

Migration Assistant comes with Mac OS (Applications -> Utilities).

Read over this KB and follow the instructions and you should be good. Also, **make sure**, on the Dell, you have **disabled** anti-virus live updates, Windows Firewall, Windows Automatic Updates, and any other software firewall; sometimes anti-virus programs will have a software firewall. These things can often cause Migration Assistant to not establish a connection with the PC.

**If Migration assistant does not work** (likely possibility), you can drag and drop files between the two computers:

**On the Mac:**
1.) Go through and create a user acct on the Mac if not already done.
2.) System Preferences -> Sharing
3.) Check off "File Sharing"
4.) Click "Options..."
5.) Make sure "Share files and folders using SMB" is checked.
6.) Below, you will see a list of user accts (or just one if that's all you've made). Check off the user acct you want to transfer your data to
7.) System Preferences -> Network. Get IP address under "status"

**On the PC**
1.) Open Windows Explorer
2.) Tools -> Map Network Drive
3.) Choose a drive letter from the dropdown menu. (Z: for example, for any other letter that is not in use by Windows)
4.)  \\ipaddressofmac\nameofhomefolderonmac
5.) Enter username and password for user acct.
6.) Should see a new window on the PC which shows the Mac's home folder
7.) Drag and drop files from the PC to the Mac

***OR....the easiest way***...Get an external hard drive (which HOPEFULLY you have or plan on purchasing). Format it NTFS or ExFAT. Drag files/folders from Windows to the ext HD. Drag and drop files onto the Mac. Done. Then reformat it Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and use it as a Time Machine backup. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: One thing: If your HD is formatted NTFS, you can drag stuff from the PC to the ext HD. You can drag stuff from the ext HD to the Mac, no problem. You cannot drag files from the Mac to the ext unless it's formatted ExFAT (which is somewhat dual platform) or Mac OS Extended (Journaled), which cannot be written to from Windows. This is why I suggested an order for formatting for your work flow. Happy transfers :)